# Use pandas to find values that match in one column but not other columns in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

```
dict1 = [{"ID": "1", "name": "tim", "OID": "12"}, 
        {"ID": "2", "name": "bob", "OID": "22"},
        {"ID": "3", "name": "rob",  "OID": "33"},
        ]

dict2 = [{"ID": "1", "name": "tim", "wrongkey": "no", "OID": "12"}, 
        {"ID": "2", "name": "difname", "wrongkey": "no", "OID": "22"},
        {"ID": "4", "name": "rob", "wrongkey": "no", "OID": "33"},
        ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict2)
```

I need to find rows in dict2 that match on dict1 ID but not on any other column. Using columns names that exist in both dataframes. But also dropping the OID column.

End result: (ID and Name are in both dataframes so just end up with that)

```
  ID     name
0  2  difname
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Code

```
# common columns except ID and OID
c = pd.Index(set(df1) & set(df2) - {'ID', 'OID'})

# Merge on ID
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on='ID', suffixes=['', '_y'])

# Compare the common columns to ensure there is no match
mask = df3[c].ne(df3[c + '_y'].values).all(axis=1)

# Filter the dataframe
df3.loc[mask, ['ID', *c]]
```

---

```
  ID     name
1  2  difname
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` and `query`:

```
out = (df2[keys].merge(df1[keys], on='ID', suffixes=(None, '_'))
                .query('name != name_').drop(columns='name_')
                .reset_index(drop=True))
print(out)

# Output
  ID     name
0  2  difname
```

Answer (score 0):

what I ended up with. maybe not the cleanest or fastest solution

```
dict1 = [{"ID": "1", "name": "tim", "OID": "12"}, 
        {"ID": "2", "name": "bob", "OID": "22"},
        {"ID": "3", "name": "rob",  "OID": "33"},
        ]

dict2 = [{"ID": "1", "name": "tim", "wrongkey": "no", "OID": "12"}, 
        {"ID": "2", "name": "difname", "wrongkey": "no", "OID": "22"},
        {"ID": "4", "name": "rob", "wrongkey": "no", "OID": "33"},
        ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict2)

df1 = df1[df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)]
df2 = df2[df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns)]
df1=df1.drop(columns=['OID'])
df2=df2.drop(columns=['OID'])

gids = df2[ df2['ID'].isin(df1['ID']) ]

merged = gids.merge(df1, indicator=True, how='outer')
merged = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only']
merged = merged.drop(columns=['_merge'])
print(merged)
```